# Не удаляется запись из базы данных sqlite

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Код ниже отправляет администратору бота список акций из бд:

```
async def del_callback_run_sale(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await delete_command_sale(callback_query.data.replace('del ', ''))
    await callback_query.answer(text=f'{callback_query.data.replace("del ", "")} удалена', show_alert=True)



async def sale_list(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        read = await read_sale()
        for rec in read:
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, rec[0], f'Название:{rec[1]}\nОписание:{rec[2]}')
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='***', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
                InlineKeyboardButton(f'Удалить {rec[1]}', callback_data=f'del {rec[1]}')
            ))
        await message.reply('Хотите добавить акцию?',
                            reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup().add(KeyboardButton('Добавить акцию')))
```

Вот сама функция удаления записи:

```
async def delete_command_sale(data):
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM sale WHERE name == ?', (data,))
    base.commit()
```

Хэндлеры зарегистрированы, названия таблицы и поля записаны корректно. Код выполняется без ошибок.

Также привожу код для взаимодействия с другой таблицей, который работает корректно:

```
async def del_callback_run_menu(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await delete_command_menu(callback_query.data.replace('del ', ''))
    await callback_query.answer(text=f'{callback_query.data.replace("del ", "")} удалена', show_alert=True)
```

```
async def delete_food(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        read = await read_menu()
        for rec in read:
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, rec[3], f'Тип:{rec[0]}\nКласс:{rec[1]}\nНазвание:{rec[2]}\n'
                                                               f'Цена:{rec[4]}\nИнгридиенты:{rec[5]}')
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='***', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
                InlineKeyboardButton(f'Удалить {rec[2]}', callback_data=f'del {rec[2]}')
            ))
```

Функция удаления из menu

```
async def delete_command_menu(data):
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM menu WHERE name == ?', (data,))
    base.commit()
```

Создание таблиц в бд:

```
def sqlite_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('db_name.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base connected')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(type TEXT,cls TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '
                 'img TEXT, price TEXT, ingridients TEXT)')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS drinks(type TEXT,cls TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '
                 'img TEXT, price TEXT, ingridients TEXT)')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sale(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, desc TEXT)')
```

Comment: `'DELETE FROM menu WHERE name = ?'` - один знак `=`

Comment: Проблема осталась.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в регистрации хендлеров

```
dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_callback_run_drinks, lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del '))
dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_callback_run_menu, lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del '))
dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_callback_run_sale, lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del '))
```

Три callback функции реагировали на одно и тоже. Исполнялась самая верхняя, то есть del_callback_run_drinks.

Фикс такой

```
dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_callback_run_menu, lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del_menu '))

dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_callback_run_drinks, lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del_drinks '))

dp.register_callback_query_handler(del_callback_run_sale, lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del_sale '))`
```

P.S Те люди, что пытались помочь, сорян за неполный код.